# If a creature with a fly Speed of 30 ft. has the Fly spell cast upon it, does it now have a 90 ft. fly speed, or only 60 ft. total?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, stacking, flight

According to the wording of the *fly* spell:

> You touch a willing creature. The target gains a flying speed of 60 feet for the duration. When the spell ends, the target falls if it is still aloft, unless it can stop the fall.

The wording of the spell says that the creature "gains" 60 feet, so I am curious if this stacks with the natural fly speed of the creature. Let us say a creature has a fly speed of 30, would that creature then get 90 feet per turn, or would it go to 60 feet?

Additionally: If a creature with a fly speed has the fly spell on them and concentration is broken, would they technically fall, if the flight speed is solely dependent on their use of the spell?

Comment: Welcome to the stack, and congratulations on a clear, well-presented and non-duplicated first question :). Do take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### It gets a fly speed of 60.

When this creature is under the affect of Fly they have these speeds:

- Fly 30ft.
- Fly 60ft.

When creatures have multiple speeds defined (e.g. Swim, Fly, Walk) they cannot move in excess of the greatest speed without taking advantage of a dash action or another feature which affects movement. When Fly is cast on it, your creature has 2 distinct Fly speeds. For this reason, it would have a maximum Fly speed of 60ft.

On the second part of the question, they would not fall as they possess a means to stop the fall via their other Fly speed.

Comment: Not as silly as it sounds!  A dragon, or a wizard with **Wings of Flying**, flies by flapping its wings. If someone entangles it by launching a net at it, it will fall -- until he casts the verbal-only **Fly** spell. Now he can fly by floating forward fast.

Comment: Ah, so the maximum of the (possibly multiple) fly abilities is what gets used. So one cannot "curse" a fast flying enemy down to 60ft speed by casting Fly on it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you've left out a word in your summary. You wrote "gains 60 feet" (of flight speed). If the spell said that then it probably would take you from 30 to 90. But it doesn't quite say that. It says "gains *a* flight speed of 60 feet". D&D tries to use plain English and that word "a" seems important. You gain a flight speed, as in you gain that ability, set at 60.

Then you're at CardboardKnight's answer -- what does it mean to have 2 movement abilities with different values of 30 and 60? It seems obvious that you have pick one (the same as if you could walk at 30 and fly at 20).

Comment: I would argue gain is a poor word choice for plain language. Clearer language would be "changes to," as in "The flight speed of the target changes to 60 feet for the duration."

Comment: No, because in that case you could reduce the flight speed of a creature by casting Fly on it. For example, you have a flight speed of 90. The someone cast fly on you. By your "changes to" rules now you flight speed is 60 max. Whereas with the "gain a flight speed" you still have your 90s.

Comment: @trlkly "gain" is the actual word D&D uses in the spell description. As you write, it's a little trickier to read than "changes to", which means it means something a little trickier -- such as getting another Fly:60, in addition to any you already have.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Ah. I get it now. Then I'd say the better wording would be "you gain the option to have Fly:60." Mostly I just think the use of the word "gain" here in the rules is confusing, and that some may be read as an "increase." Hence the "plain meaning" isn't nearly as clear. I do think you have it right, though.